# Free spider chart API

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I am looking for a free api to make spider charts. I noticed Google charts does not have them.

Here's an [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider)

All the ones I have found so far require you to purchase a license

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExtJs has spider charts:

Is this what you're talking about: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/charts/RadarFill.html

Comment: That Is exactly What I want. But its not free from what I can tell

Comment: Yes it is- it's open source.  http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/  They say it's a 45 day trial but I've been using it for years

Comment: that doesnt seem right to me if it says 45 day trial

Comment: It's just a javascript library that you download.  They post all of their source code.  For example:http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Controller.html#Ext-app-Controller

Answer (score 1):

Flot seems to have a plugin for this: http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=138

I've not used it, nor do I know a whole lot about it, but I have used Flot extensively and love it.